# HQL order by criteria

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I met a problem with SQL.

Assume this is my native SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM products 
ORDER BY balance <= bottleneck DESC, product_code ASC
```

This is working at postgressql. But it doesn't work with HQL. My HQL as following:

```
from Products as p order by  p.balance < p.bottleneck desc, p.productCode asc
```

And I met exception as following:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: < near line 1, column 67 [from com.inventory.inventory.vo.Products as p order by  p.balance < p.bottleneck]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1760)
    at com.inventory.inventory.dao.impl.ProductsDAOImpl.getProducts(ProductsDAOImpl.java:72)
    at Main.main(Main.java:43)
```

Is any way to solve for this query?

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Best rgds,
A1ucard

Comment: can you explain what `ORDER BY balance <= bottleneck` does for people not familiar with Postgres? I don't think it's standard SQL. This would probably help get you a useful answer faster.

Comment: get all the result and sorted by the balance < bottleneck at the first priority, and the rest is sort by product code.

Comment: But what does it mean for the results to be "sorted by the balance < bottleneck"?

Comment: @mattb means, the records where balance < bottleneck would be sorted at first place follow by those records sorted by product code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't got Hibernate installed right now, but this should work:

```
from Products as p where p.balance < p.bottleneck order by p.bottlenec desc, p.productCode asc
```

This is a more "standard" way of writing SQL because you put order *after* the where clause.

**Edit:**

There doesn't seem to be a way to do what you want, at least not using HQL. Postgres has a much more powerful ORDER BY clause than HQL has.

Postgres [documentation on select clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-select.html) has "ORDER BY ***expression***", where expression has [it's own documentation page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-expressions.html).

On the other hand, Hibernate's [order by clause](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-ordering) is very limited. It allows you to order columns and use regular or aggregate functions.

The deal killer is this sentence:

> Neither the group by clause nor the order by clause can contain
>   arithmetic expressions.

So, it seems you are out of luck and you must use native SQL if you want to obtain a resultset that you need.

Comment: Thanks for reply, this is not the result I prefer. Your way is work but the result is only display for the records where the balance < bottleneck. I prefer I can get all the result and sorted by the balance < bottleneck at the first priority, and the rest is sort by product code.

Comment: Oh I See... Thanks for explanation anyway. Maybe I will try to use Java comparator to sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with PostreSQL syntax, but

```
balance <= b
```

part should be in the where close. In HQL you can not apply Postgre SQL specific syntax.